# What allocator for a boost.lockfree inter-thread fifo?

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-management, boost, lock-free

I would like to know what would be the good allocators to use with Boost.Lockfree FIFO.

I'm using the SPSC queue of this library, for a communication I have to do in a critical thread. The message is then packaged with a data chunk of a variable size.
The easy solution is to use an existing one, but Which?

- Boost.Pool : Is it lock free ?
- Boost.Circular_buffer : is it lockfree ?
- Boost.Interprocess (is said to be compatible with lockfree but I don't need interprocess)
- tlsf -> This is a bit too much for my problem but why not (in this case, I would probably use it for more than this issue, But I could not build it on windows)
- hand made stupid pool with constant block size of the maximum of the message datasize (possible, this would use more memroy, but is my back up solution currently) -> BTW couldn't I do that with Boost.Pool instead?

Thank you for your ideas.

Comment: Why not the default one?

Comment: You mean the default allocator ? Because it locks. Or to be more precise, Depending on the runtime context, the execution of a malloc based allocator can not be ensured to be below a certain time of execution.

Comment: The default allocator is [`boost::lockfree::allocator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/allocator.html). Does it lock?

Comment: I think this is a policy (I mean it is just a template trick of Boost to manage parameters of its classes, but it does not implement anything). I will check but really I think this is not an allocator implementation.